# Replacing text of nested span

Tags: javascript, html

I have an innerHTML of one span (outer) collected in one varaiable.

Now there is one nested span inside span Inner, so can I set the innerHTMl of span text as follows?

```
var outertext = document.getElementById("outer");
```

Now outertext has inner span, and I want to replace text of inner span.

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you try to explain more cleary what it is you want? I can't really understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Get the span ;)

```
outertext.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 'O_o'
```

Replace `0` with whatever suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write less, you can use jQuery:

```
$('#outer > span').html('new content here');
```

If the span is not a direct child of #outer, remove the `>`.

If you don't want to use anything but native functions, see the other two answers.

Comment: jQuery isn't the only answer, and it's selector engine is actually sizzle. http://mootools.net/slickspeed/ -- That being said, I love jQuery... most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
outertext.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = "NEW CONTENT";
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/JAmFM/

*(Note that it is `getElementById`. You had `getElementbyid`. Maybe a typo.)*

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you do not want to use jQuery, you can do it with pure JavaScript by using `querySelector()`:

```
document.querySelector('#outer > span').innerHTML = "New content here";
```